# Using google accounts to get info and store on server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

I am creating an app and want to use the google accounts on the Android phone to get the user's email, name and possibly phone number.  How can I securely communicate with a rails server?  I could send the auth token but my understanding is that it changes often.  I plan on making a private API token for very basic auth but I need a user specific authentication as well.  I thought about using an email hash and sending that but there has to be a better solution.

Normally what I would do if the account logins were on the server is login and send a token back and check that token to the database every request but can't do that since I login on the client side.

What would be my best bet to implement something where I log in on the android side but store info on the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer... Uses Google Play API to get a token and verify on server/client side.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html